# How can I match the line which isn't based on the first line?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this:

```
$str = "aacbbaaaa
        vvnmmvvvv
        bbtuucccc    // this
        rroxxrrrr";
```

**Always first line of the string is the main pattern**. In the string above, all lines have same pattern except third line. Because 4 last characters should be the same two first characters, So to make third line correct, it should be `bbtuubbbb`.

---

Let me say another example:

```
$str = "abacb
        mrmyr
        qfqvf
        lelol";    // this
```

In the string above, last line has different pattern. Because its last character isn't the same its second character. To make it correct, it should be `leloe`.

---

Anyway I would like to match different-pattern line. Is it possible to I do that using regex?

Comment: You can't generate a pattern looking at the input test

Comment: Sorry ! I don't actually get your question. Do you mean to say that the Regex should identify the pattern from the first string and match subsequent strings ?

Comment: @noob Yes exactly.

Comment: @stack: **Waiting for the day some AI will be capable of it.**

Comment: @stack: I said that because RegEx is not capable of identifying the patterns just by looking at string. You have to construct regex to match patterns.. You can parse a multiple strings of same type, do some programming and come up with short possible pattern out of many possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you need a working *non-RegEx* example, here it is

```
<?
$str = "aacbbaaaa
        vvnmmvvvv
        bbtuucccc
        rroxxrrrr";

$lines = array_map('trim', explode("\n", $str));

define('STR_LEN', strlen($lines[0]));
define('STR_COUNT', count($lines));

$pattern = getPattern($lines[0]);

for ($i = 1; $i < STR_COUNT; $i++) {
    $line = $lines[$i];
    if ($pattern != getPattern($line)) {
        echo $line . "\n";
    }
}

//-------------------------

function getPattern($str) {
    $result = '';
    $dictionary = [];
    $counter = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < STR_LEN; $i++) {
        if (!array_key_exists($str[$i], $dictionary)) {
            $dictionary[$str[$i]] = $counter++;
        }
        $result .= $dictionary[$str[$i]] . '.';
    }

    return $result;
}
```